# Activate particular drop-down list when user selects the radio button in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Before I explain my problem, below is my simple code

```
<body>

    <div>   
        <input type="radio" name="salary"/>Per Year
            <select>
                <option value="0">All</option>
                <option value="40000">$40,000.00+</option>
                <option value="50000">$50,000.00+</option>

            </select>
    </div>


    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="salary"/>Per Hour
          <select>
                <option value="0">All</option>
                <option value="20">$20.00+</option>
                <option value="25">$25.00+</option>

            </select>
     </div
</body>
```

What am I trying to achieve is when user selects radio button with value "Per Year".I want to disable the other radio button[with value "Per Hour"].So he can't select the values from other drop-down list.

How can I do this in AngularJS?Is their any directive that could solve this??

Comment: bind the form controls with `ng-model` and use `ng-disabled` to watch them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/boqexu/1/edit

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">
     <div>
        <input type="radio"  name="salary" ng-model="type" value="year"/>Per Year
            <select ng-model="year.value" ng-disabled="type =='hour'">
                <option value="0">All</option>
                <option value="40000">$40,000.00+</option>
                <option value="50000">$50,000.00+</option>

            </select>
    </div>


    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="salary" ng-model="type" value="hour"/>Per Hour
          <select ng-disabled="type =='year'" ng-model="hour.value">
                <option value="0">All</option>
                <option value="20">$20.00+</option>
                <option value="25">$25.00+</option>

            </select>
    </div>



      </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Is it possible to reset the drop-down values when toggling?

Comment: @lear what do you means by reset

Comment: I want to reset to default/original values, in my case "ALL" once user toggles.

Comment: You're welcome. I will appreciate if you can mark question as resolved